Lost SSH access after enabling ufw for MySQL on Ubuntu instance
I've an instance created in my aws account, this instance was created with Ubuntu image system, the sequence of the packages installation is, Java and MySQL, after install mysql I initiate the configuration of UFW for 3306 port to communicate Workbench Windows to mysql on ubuntu, when I type the command "ufw enable" the ufw says that ssh can be destroyed  and ask me "yes" or "no", after answering "yes" I lose my ubuntu system, if I open another connection to my ip address the result is:
 "Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in the following places
 * /bin/dircolors
 * /usr/bin/dircolors
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found" 

but I don't have access to any command of ubuntu system. I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.
Thanks and best regards.

Sounds like your firewall warned you that it was going to shut down the ssh connection you were using and you did it anyway. Did you try writing firewall rules that allow ssh, since you obviously need that?

That does not look like a problem with UFW, that looks like a problem with your shell environment. Do you have a log of the terminal session where you ran ufw that shows exactly what you ran and what it said?
The errors you see mean the PATH variable, which tells the shell where to find executables, is either not set or is missing critical directories.
I'm not sure how running ufw could do that to your system, but if you can get in and run /bin/ufw reset (as root) that will undo any changes you made to it and return it to defaults. If your environment is broken that probably won't help though.
You say "I open another connection to my ip address", but also "I don't have access to any command of ubuntu system". Does this mean you can still connect to the VM you created, but when you log in you get the error about 'lesspipe' etc.?
If you have a shell prompt when you reconnect to the VM, can you run echo $PATH? echo is a built-in command in the shell, so doesn't need PATH to be set.
Here's what the output should look like (there may be other directories, this is just the default set):
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

If it prints nothing, or prints out a string of directories that does not contain /usr/bin and /bin try running this (the first two characters are a dot and a space) . /etc/environment. It should not print anything, but it will set the PATH in your shell back to the system default and let you run things.
If that worked, you can run . ~/.bashrc. That also won't print anything but it should set your shell up properly. This is not permanent, you will need to do it again if you exit the shell and log back in, but it should get rid of the immediate errors so you can see what has gone wrong to cause them.
